# How do I groupby simple dataframe, my code is not giving expected output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to groupby on simple pandas Data Frame, but it is not working as expected.
My Dataframe is as below:

[my df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK3G2.jpg)

I have to groupby by MetroArea so that all the Teams should align under one MetroArea.
For instance, Against New York City, it should align Rangers, Islanders and Devils.
I am using below code, but it seems it is not showing me the output as expected.

df.groupby(['MetroArea']).head()

Output:
[this is the output which I am not expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1WsO.png)

I want something like this:
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow9Fo.jpg)

Please help with the code.

Thanks
Gaurav

Comment: Please provide the minimal, reproducible example. Do not use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code. This helps others more easily read and test your code.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try like below example.

```
import pandas as pd
technologies   = ({
'Cities':["NY","CA","GA","KY","NY","CA","GA","KY", "CA","GA","KY"],
'Team' :['ABC','FGR', 'GBP','ABC','FGR', 'GBP','KLM','PQR', 'MBP','ABC','FGR']})
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)
print(df)

grouped_df = df.groupby(['Cities', 'Team']).size()
print(grouped_df)
```

Comment: Please select this answer if it serves the purpose.